# bash script check strings in file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

How do I do something like:

```
if !("abc" in file1 and "def" in file2)
then
  echo "Failed"
fi
```

I've already known how to check "abc" in file1: `grep -Fxq "abc" file1`, but I can't manage to get the `if not (command1 and command2)` part to work.

Comment: Use De-morgans law - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws - i.e. "not(A and B)" becomes "not A or not B"

Comment: Thanks, the problem is I don't know how to write it using bash script...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got it almost right. Just add a space between the exclamation mark and the grep commands, and it would work:

```
if ! (grep -Fxq "abc" file1 && grep -Fxq "def" file2); then
     echo "Failed"
fi
```

Assuming `bash`, there is no need for extra `else`.

Note that using parenthesis runs the greps in a subshell environment, as a child shell process. You can easily avoid this by using curly braces (this thing is called group command):

```
if ! { grep -Fxq "abc" file1 && grep -Fxq "def" file2; }; then
     echo "Failed"
fi
```

Note that you need more spaces and an additional semicolon – isn't `bash` syntax just so funny!?!

Comment: What specifically does not work? Are you using `bash` (`{` ... `}` construct is `bash` extension)?

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
$ grep -Fxq "abc" file1 && grep -Fxq "def" file2 || echo "Failed"
```

This uses the `bash` logical operators AND `&&` and OR `||`.

This can be split over multiple lines like:

```
$ grep -Fxq "abc" file1 && 
> grep -Fxq "def" file2 ||
> echo "Failed"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (grep -Fxq "abc" file1 && grep -Fxq "def" file2);
then
  echo ""
else
  echo "failed"
fi
```

Comment: exactly the same, I've written, +1

Comment: @chepner I used OP's code snippet to answer his question. Corrected it now.